# unable to install wxPython on Ubuntu with python3.7 using pip3

Tags: wxpython, python-3.7

I have to install **wxPython**.

I have,

- Ubuntu 18.10
- python version: **Python 3.7.3**
- pip3 version: **pip 19.0.3**

from /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7) I run command,

```
pip3 install wxPython
```

it through the following errors:

> Checking for /tmp/pip-install-mjeu3aw7/wxpython/bin/waf-2.0.8...
>       "/usr/local/bin/python3.7" /tmp/pip-install-mjeu3aw7/wxpython/bin/waf-2.0.8
>   --wx_config=/tmp/pip-install-mjeu3aw7/wxpython/build/wxbld/gtk3/wx-config
>   --gtk3 --python="/usr/local/bin/python3.7" --out=build/waf/3.7/gtk3 configure build
>       Setting top to                           : /tmp/pip-install-mjeu3aw7/wxpython
>       Setting out to                           : /tmp/pip-install-mjeu3aw7/wxpython/build/waf/3.7/gtk3
>       Checking for 'gcc' (C compiler)          : /usr/bin/gcc
>       Checking for 'g++' (C++ compiler)        : /usr/bin/g++
>       Checking for program 'python'            : /usr/local/bin/python3.7
>       Checking for python version >= 2.7.0     : 3.7.3
>       python-config                            : /usr/local/bin/python3.7-config
>       Asking python-config for pyembed '--cflags --libs --ldflags' flags : yes
>       Testing pyembed configuration                                      : yes
>       Asking python-config for pyext '--cflags --libs --ldflags' flags   : yes
>       Testing pyext configuration                                        : Could not build python extensions
>       The configuration failed
>       (complete log in /tmp/pip-install-mjeu3aw7/wxpython/build/waf/3.7/gtk3/config.log)
>       Command '"/usr/local/bin/python3.7" /tmp/pip-install-mjeu3aw7/wxpython/bin/waf-2.0.8
>   --wx_config=/tmp/pip-install-mjeu3aw7/wxpython/build/wxbld/gtk3/wx-config
>   --gtk3 --python="/usr/local/bin/python3.7" --out=build/waf/3.7/gtk3 configure build ' failed with exit code 1.
>       Finished command: build_py (0.852s)
>       Finished command: build (2m51.322s)
>       Command '"/usr/local/bin/python3.7" -u build.py build' failed with exit code 1.
>
> ---------------------------------------- Command "/usr/local/bin/python3.7 -u -c "import setuptools,
>   tokenize;**file**='/tmp/pip-install-mjeu3aw7/wxpython/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize,
>   'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n',
>   '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install
>   --record /tmp/pip-record-o0jpf739/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-mjeu3aw7/wxpython/

Can anybody give me the exact installation working solutions or how to proceed?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

wxPython does not natively support wheels building for Linux.

If you're on Ubuntu, try the following [according to their documentation](https://wxpython.org/pages/downloads/):

```
pip install -U \
    -f https://extras.wxpython.org/wxPython4/extras/linux/gtk3/ubuntu-18.04 \
    wxPython
```

If you're not on [any of the supported extras](https://extras.wxpython.org/wxPython4/extras/linux/gtk3/) or the above doesn't work, you'll have to build it yourself according to their directions on their Downloads page.

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 18.10.

Comment: @2017kamb try the wheels at `https://extras.wxpython.org/wxPython4/extras/linux/gtk3/ubuntu-18.04`

Comment: I just replace pip with pip3 since I am using python 3.7

Comment: In case you do want to build your own wheels on Linux there is some info about that here: https://wxpython.org/blog/2017-08-17-builds-for-linux-with-pip/