# How to fix: "Testing pyext configuration : Could not build python extensions"

Tags: python, python-3.x, redhat, wxpython

I am trying to install wxPython but the wheel build fails. The error message is not helpful in indicating what to do or where to look to fix this. Can anyone please help me understand how to build this wheel correctly?

```
Machine: Linux on Power (this is not x86)
OS: RHEL Server, 7.5 (Maipo)
python version: Python 3.6.4
pip3 version: pip 19.3.1
```

I noticed [this stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55686679/unable-to-install-wxpython-on-ubuntu-with-python3-7-using-pip3), which is also not helpful because my linux release is not on the list of the ones provided.

Following links above I tried [wxPython download page](https://wxpython.org/pages/downloads/) and the following [install with pip](https://wxpython.org/blog/2017-08-17-builds-for-linux-with-pip/) but in step 5 basically tells you "look at the log and figure it out"....not helpful.

I tried to manually hack the wxPython package using my very limited competence and removed some dependency.....still nothing.

```
<...>
  Finished command: build_wx (1m56.907s)
  Running command: build_py
  Checking for /tmp/pip-req-build-dgnp13sp/bin/waf-2.0.8...
  "/afs/apd.pok.ibm.com/u/mfacchin/wxenvlop/bin/python3" /tmp/pip-req-build-dgnp13sp/bin/waf-2.0.8 --wx_config=/tmp/pip-req-build-dgnp13sp/build/wxbld/gtk3/wx-config --gtk3 --python="/afs/apd.pok.ibm.com/u/mfacchin/wxenvlop/bin/python3" --out=build/waf/3.6/gtk3 configure build
  Setting top to                           : /tmp/pip-req-build-dgnp13sp
  Setting out to                           : /tmp/pip-req-build-dgnp13sp/build/waf/3.6/gtk3
  Checking for 'gcc' (C compiler)          : /bin/gcc
  Checking for 'g++' (C++ compiler)        : /bin/g++
  Checking for program 'python'            : /afs/apd.pok.ibm.com/u/mfacchin/wxenvlop/bin/python3
  Checking for python version >= 2.7.0     : 3.6.4
  python-config                            : /opt/xsite/cte/tools/python/3.6/bin/python3.6-config
  Asking python-config for pyext '--cflags --libs --ldflags' flags : yes
  Testing pyext configuration                                      : Could not build python extensions
  The configuration failed
  (complete log in /tmp/pip-req-build-dgnp13sp/build/waf/3.6/gtk3/config.log)
  Command '"/afs/apd.pok.ibm.com/u/mfacchin/wxenvlop/bin/python3" /tmp/pip-req-build-dgnp13sp/bin/waf-2.0.8 --wx_config=/tmp/pip-req-build-dgnp13sp/build/wxbld/gtk3/wx-config --gtk3 --python="/afs/apd.pok.ibm.com/u/mfacchin/wxenvlop/bin/python3" --out=build/waf/3.6/gtk3 configure build ' failed with exit code 1.
  Finished command: build_py (0m6.991s)
  Finished command: build (2m3.899s)
  Command '"/afs/apd.pok.ibm.com/u/mfacchin/wxenvlop/bin/python3" -u build.py build' failed with exit code 1.
  Building wheel for wxPython (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for wxPython
<...>
```

----Update 12/2 (After Robin Dunn's feedback)
Thank you Robin for the directives. Following is the last portion of the config.log from a different run using the build command. Also the error message is slightly different (below, following the config.log), because I had previously used the explicit wheel-build command: pip wheel -v wxPython-4.0.7.post1.tar.gz  2>&1 | tee build.log. Does this log below confirm your theory regarding the Python built with the --enable-shared configure flag?

```
Testing pyext configuration
==>

#include <Python.h>
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
    void Py_Initialize(void);
    void Py_Finalize(void);
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   (void)argc; (void)argv;
   Py_Initialize();
   Py_Finalize();
   return 0;
}

<==
[1/2] Compiling [32mbuild/waf/3.6/gtk3/.conf_check_cfc3ecfbbf37890054f6518ca7961071/test.cpp[0m

['/bin/g++', '-fPIC', '-g', '-fwrapv', '-O3', '-I../../../../../../../../../../../../../../cte/tools/python/vol2/.3.6.4-linux-ppc64le/include/python3.6m', '-I/opt/xsite/cte/tools/python/common2018/include', '-DPYTHONDIR="/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages"', '-DPYTHONARCHDIR="/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages"', '-DNDEBUG', '../test.cpp', '-c', '-o/afs/apd.pok.ibm.com/func/vlsi/eclipz/sf5/usr/mfacchin/c01/python_venv/wxenv191202/wxPython-4.0.7.post1_mf1/build/waf/3.6/gtk3/.conf_check_cfc3ecfbbf37890054f6518ca7961071/testbuild/test.cpp.1.o']
[2/2] Linking [33mbuild/waf/3.6/gtk3/.conf_check_cfc3ecfbbf37890054f6518ca7961071/testbuild/testprog.cpython-36m-powerpc64le-linux-gnu.so[0m

['/bin/g++', '-shared', '-Xlinker', '-export-dynamic', 'test.cpp.1.o', '-o', '/afs/apd.pok.ibm.com/func/vlsi/eclipz/sf5/usr/mfacchin/c01/python_venv/wxenv191202/wxPython-4.0.7.post1_mf1/build/waf/3.6/gtk3/.conf_check_cfc3ecfbbf37890054f6518ca7961071/testbuild/testprog.cpython-36m-powerpc64le-linux-gnu.so', '-Wl,-Bstatic', '-Wl,-Bdynamic', '-L/afs/apd.pok.ibm.com/func/vlsi/cte/tools/python/vol2/.3.6.4-linux-ppc64le/lib/python3.6/config-3.6m-powerpc64le-linux-gnu', '-L/afs/apd.pok.ibm.com/func/vlsi/cte/tools/python/vol2/.3.6.4-linux-ppc64le/lib', '-lpython3.6m', '-lpthread', '-ldl', '-lutil', '-lm', '-lpython3.6m', '-lpthread', '-ldl', '-lutil', '-lm']
err: /bin/ld: /afs/apd.pok.ibm.com/func/vlsi/cte/tools/python/vol2/.3.6.4-linux-ppc64le/lib/python3.6/config-3.6m-powerpc64le-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.a(Python-ast.o): In function `obj2ast_keyword':
/data/ubrandt/Python-3.6.4/Python/Python-ast.c:7767:(.text.unlikely+0x608): call to `_Py_keyword' lacks nop, can't restore toc; recompile with -fPIC
/bin/ld: /afs/apd.pok.ibm.com/func/vlsi/cte/tools/python/vol2/.3.6.4-linux-ppc64le/lib/python3.6/config-3.6m-powerpc64le-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.a(Python-ast.o): In function `obj2ast_comprehension':
/data/ubrandt/Python-3.6.4/Python/Python-ast.c:7419:(.text.unlikely+0x9f4): call to `_Py_comprehension' lacks nop, can't restore toc; recompile with -fPIC
/bin/ld: /afs/apd.pok.ibm.com/func/vlsi/cte/tools/python/vol2/.3.6.4-linux-ppc64le/lib/python3.6/config-3.6m-powerpc64le-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.a(Python-ast.o): In function `obj2ast_alias':
/data/ubrandt/Python-3.6.4/Python/Python-ast.c:7802:(.text.unlikely+0xbec): call to `_Py_alias' lacks nop, can't restore toc; recompile with -fPIC
/bin/ld: /afs/apd.pok.ibm.com/func/vlsi/cte/tools/python/vol2/.3.6.4-linux-ppc64le/lib/python3.6/config-3.6m-powerpc64le-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.a(Python-ast.o): In function `obj2ast_withitem':
/data/ubrandt/Python-3.6.4/Python/Python-ast.c:7837:(.text.unlikely+0xdd4): call to `_Py_withitem' lacks nop, can't restore toc; recompile with -fPIC
/bin/ld: final link failed: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

from /afs/apd.pok.ibm.com/func/vlsi/eclipz/sf5/usr/mfacchin/c01/python_venv/wxenv191202/wxPython-4.0.7.post1_mf1: Test does not build: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/afs/apd.pok.ibm.com/func/vlsi/eclipz/sf5/usr/mfacchin/c01/python_venv/wxenv191202/wxPython-4.0.7.post1_mf1/bin/.waf3-2.0.8-206f2b7a89029e71942a2beb9e1bbbbd/waflib/Configure.py", line 324, in run_build
    bld.compile()
  File "/afs/apd.pok.ibm.com/func/vlsi/eclipz/sf5/usr/mfacchin/c01/python_venv/wxenv191202/wxPython-4.0.7.post1_mf1/bin/.waf3-2.0.8-206f2b7a89029e71942a2beb9e1bbbbd/waflib/Build.py", line 176, in compile
    raise Errors.BuildError(self.producer.error)
waflib.Errors.BuildError: Build failed
 -> task in 'testprog' failed with exit status 1 (run with -v to display more information)

Could not build python extensions
from /.....: The configuration failed
```

and this is the error message that I get this new run, slightly different

```
msgfmt --verbose -c -o zh_TW.mo zh_TW.po
1710 translated messages, 82 fuzzy translations, 61 untranslated messages.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/afs/apd.pok.ibm.com/func/vlsi/eclipz/sf5/usr/mfacchin/c01/python_venv/wxenv191202/wxPython-4.0.7.post1_mf1/ext/wxWidgets/locale'
Setting top to                           : /afs/apd.pok.ibm.com/func/vlsi/eclipz/sf5/usr/mfacchin/c01/python_venv/wxenv191202/wxPython-4.0.7.post1_mf1 
Setting out to                           : /afs/apd.pok.ibm.com/func/vlsi/eclipz/sf5/usr/mfacchin/c01/python_venv/wxenv191202/wxPython-4.0.7.post1_mf1/build/waf/3.6/gtk3 
Checking for 'gcc' (C compiler)          : /bin/gcc 
Checking for 'g++' (C++ compiler)        : /bin/g++ 
Checking for program 'python'            : /afs/apd.pok.ibm.com/func/vlsi/eclipz/sf5/usr/mfacchin/c01/python_venv/wxenv191202/bin/python3 
Checking for python version >= 2.7.0     : 3.6.4 
python-config                            : /opt/xsite/cte/tools/python/3.6/bin/python3.6-config 
Asking python-config for pyext '--cflags --libs --ldflags' flags : yes 
Testing pyext configuration                                      : Could not build python extensions 
The configuration failed
(complete log in /afs/apd.pok.ibm.com/func/vlsi/eclipz/sf5/usr/mfacchin/c01/python_venv/wxenv191202/wxPython-4.0.7.post1_mf1/build/waf/3.6/gtk3/config.log)
Will build using: "/afs/apd.pok.ibm.com/func/vlsi/eclipz/sf5/usr/mfacchin/c01/python_venv/wxenv191202/bin/python3"
3.6.4 (default, Feb 12 2018, 16:08:32) 
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-16)]
Python's architecture is 64bit
cfg.VERSION: 4.0.7.post1

Running command: build
Running command: build_wx
wxWidgets build options: ['--wxpython', '--unicode', '--gtk3']
Configure options: ['--enable-unicode', '--with-gtk=3', '--enable-sound', '--enable-graphics_ctx', '--enable-display', '--enable-geometry', '--enable-debug_flag', '--enable-optimise', '--disable-debugreport', '--enable-uiactionsim', '--enable-autoidman', '--with-sdl']
/afs/apd.pok.ibm.com/func/vlsi/eclipz/sf5/usr/mfacchin/c01/python_venv/wxenv191202/wxPython-4.0.7.post1_mf1/ext/wxWidgets/configure --enable-unicode --with-gtk=3 --enable-sound --enable-graphics_ctx --enable-display --enable-geometry --enable-debug_flag --enable-optimise --disable-debugreport --enable-uiactionsim --enable-autoidman --with-sdl
make --jobs=128
Building message catalogs in /afs/apd.pok.ibm.com/func/vlsi/eclipz/sf5/usr/mfacchin/c01/python_venv/wxenv191202/wxPython-4.0.7.post1_mf1/ext/wxWidgets/locale
make allmo
Finished command: build_wx (12m36.623s)
Running command: build_py
Checking for /afs/apd.pok.ibm.com/func/vlsi/eclipz/sf5/usr/mfacchin/c01/python_venv/wxenv191202/wxPython-4.0.7.post1_mf1/bin/waf-2.0.8...
"/afs/apd.pok.ibm.com/func/vlsi/eclipz/sf5/usr/mfacchin/c01/python_venv/wxenv191202/bin/python3" /afs/apd.pok.ibm.com/func/vlsi/eclipz/sf5/usr/mfacchin/c01/python_venv/wxenv191202/wxPython-4.0.7.post1_mf1/bin/waf-2.0.8 --wx_config=/afs/apd.pok.ibm.com/func/vlsi/eclipz/sf5/usr/mfacchin/c01/python_venv/wxenv191202/wxPython-4.0.7.post1_mf1/build/wxbld/gtk3/wx-config --gtk3 --python="/afs/apd.pok.ibm.com/func/vlsi/eclipz/sf5/usr/mfacchin/c01/python_venv/wxenv191202/bin/python3" --out=build/waf/3.6/gtk3 configure build 
Command '"/afs/apd.pok.ibm.com/func/vlsi/eclipz/sf5/usr/mfacchin/c01/python_venv/wxenv191202/bin/python3" /afs/apd.pok.ibm.com/func/vlsi/eclipz/sf5/usr/mfacchin/c01/python_venv/wxenv191202/wxPython-4.0.7.post1_mf1/bin/waf-2.0.8 --wx_config=/afs/apd.pok.ibm.com/func/vlsi/eclipz/sf5/usr/mfacchin/c01/python_venv/wxenv191202/wxPython-4.0.7.post1_mf1/build/wxbld/gtk3/wx-config --gtk3 --python="/afs/apd.pok.ibm.com/func/vlsi/eclipz/sf5/usr/mfacchin/c01/python_venv/wxenv191202/bin/python3" --out=build/waf/3.6/gtk3 configure build ' failed with exit code 1.
Finished command: build_py (2m7.118s)
Finished command: build (14m43.742s)
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you might be using a custom Python build. Was your Python built with the `--enable-shared` configure flag? On Linux platforms the waf build tool assumes that Python was built that way, and will try to link with the Python shared library, and will fail if it is not present.

If that doesn't help then you can get more details from waf's configure log. When using pip to do the build then it will have removed the temporary build folders before you can get at them. So if you unpack the source archive and do the build with `python3 build.py build` you'll be able to find the log in `./build/waf/3.6/gtk3/config.log` and hopefully find some useful clues there.

Comment: Hi Robin, thanks you for the directions. I edited my post above to add the config.log content. Do you believe that it might confirm your theory regarding the --enable-shared? My IT group was unable to confirm/deny.

Comment: Perhaps. Look in `/afs/apd.pok.ibm.com/func/vlsi/cte/tools/python/vol2/.3.6.4-linux-ppc64le/lib/python3.6/config-3.6m-powerpc64le-linux-gnu` and see if there is a `libpython3.6m.so` file or link present. If not then Python was not configured with `--enable-shared`. Otherwise, I'm not familiar with some of the other error messages in the log fragment. From some googling it looks like it may be a powerpc64-specific issue, and I don't have much experience there.

Comment: You are right Robin, the file in there has a different extension: `libpython3.6m.a`, so, based on your feedback, it would seem python has been built without the `--enable-shared`.
You mentioned that is a "default" assumption for waf. Is there a way to make waf change behavior? I am trying to use the global python installation in my organization and they will not change that because it could jeopardize other applications.