# How to load a local version of python using pyenv

Tags: python, pyenv

I am trying to install wxPython on Manjaro and it complains:

```
Asking python-config for pyext '--cflags --libs --ldflags' flags : not found
```

Searching [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58712734/how-to-fix-testing-pyext-configuration-could-not-build-python-extensions) it seems that python has not been compiled using --enable-shared

I have compiled a python version using --enable-shared and it is installed in

```
~/python13.3
```

How can I add this version to pyenv so that I can use it in a virtual environment?