# Pipenv creates virtualenv, then complains about not finding suitable Python, but it runs anyway

Tags: python, virtualenv, pipenv

I compiled Python 3.7.17 with `pyenv`:

```bash
    $ env PYTHON_CONFIGURE_OPTS="--enable-shared" pyenv install 3.7.17
    Downloading Python-3.7.17.tar.xz...
    -> https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.17/Python-3.7.17.tar.xz
    Installing Python-3.7.17...
    patching file Doc/library/ctypes.rst
    patching file Lib/test/test_unicode.py
    patching file Modules/_ctypes/_ctypes.c
    patching file Modules/_ctypes/callproc.c
    patching file Modules/_ctypes/ctypes.h
    patching file setup.py
    patching file 'Misc/NEWS.d/next/Core and Builtins/2020-06-30-04-44-29.bpo-41100.PJwA6F.rst'
    patching file Modules/_decimal/libmpdec/mpdecimal.h
    patching file setup.py
    Installed Python-3.7.17 to /home/username/.pyenv/versions/3.7.17
```

Now I'm trying to set up a pipenv using that version, and it seems to work...

```bash
$ pipenv install python 3.7.17
Creating a virtualenv for this project...
Pipfile: /home/username/my_env/Pipfile
Using /home/username/.pyenv/versions/3.7.17/bin/python3.7m (3.7.17) to create virtualenv...
⠹ Creating virtual environment...created virtual environment CPython3.7.17.final.0-64 in 136ms
  creator CPython3Posix(dest=/home/username/.local/share/virtualenvs/my_env-_8TM2tw_, clear=False, no_vcs_ignore=False, global=False)
  seeder FromAppData(download=False, pip=bundle, setuptools=bundle, wheel=bundle, via=copy, app_data_dir=/home/username/.local/share/virtualenv)
    added seed packages: pip==23.1.2, setuptools==68.0.0, wheel==0.40.0
  activators BashActivator,CShellActivator,FishActivator,NushellActivator,PowerShellActivator,PythonActivatoras it should

✔ Successfully created virtual environment! 
Virtualenv location: /home/username/.local/share/virtualenvs/my_env-_8TM2tw_
```

...until it does not?

```bash
Installing python...as it should
Error:  An error occurred while installing python!
Error text: 
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for python

✘ Installation Failed
```

...but then it works anyway:

```bash
$ pipenv shell
Launching subshell in virtual environment...
 . /home/username/.local/share/virtualenvs/my_env-_8TM2tw_/bin/activate
username@TUD259847-ubuntu:~/my_env$  . /home/username/.local/share/virtualenvs/my_env-_8TM2tw_/bin/activate
(my_env) username@TUD259847-ubuntu:~/my_env$ python
Python 3.7.17 (default, Jul 18 2023, 20:23:41) 
[GCC 9.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

I could just accept this and move on, but I'd like to understand what's going on here, and I need to make sure that Python is working correctly, because further down the line, I'm getting cryptic errors trying to compile wxpython (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76714994/recover-config-log-after-failed-pip-install)), and I'd like to make sure that this issue is not the reason for the mystery compiler problems I see further down the road...

Comment: Why do you need to compile a (no longer supported) Python?  Do you need an older unsupported version?

Comment: @stdunbar: exactly. I need to use a package which supports no newer Python version than 3.7, and have not found any binary releases for 3.7.17.

Comment: You cannot install Python with `pipenv` — it's a wrapper for `pip`+`virtualenv`, it can only install python libraries but not Python itself. Most probably you meant `pyenv install 3.7.17` but you've already installed Python 3.7.17 so you don't need the command at all.

Answer (score 1):

D'oh!

the correct syntax to create a pipenv environment with a specific python version is

```
pipenv install --python 3.7.17
```

(notice the `--` in front of python? That makes it an argument)
I wonder why the command didn't just give me an error directly, and even knew which python version to pick, but that's for another time.